Is FrozenDictionary<TKey,TValue> thread safe in .NET 8?
Is it safe to read concurrently from an instance of FrozenDictionary<TKey,TValue> from different threads?
I assume this type being thread safe, since it is immutable, but curiously its thread safety is not explicitly documented (I can't find any mention to it by looking at the official documentation. Am I looking at the wrong place?).
In my experience, thread safety is always explicitly documented in Microsoft documentation and it is never granted as "implicit". For instance, the thread safety of ImmutableDictionary<TKey,TValue> is explicitly documented.
Does anyone has a clue on this?

Is there a reason you'd prefer to use FrozenDictionary<,> over ImmutableDictionary<,>, given the latter gives you the guarantee you appear to be seeking?

I would go with the ImmutableDictionary<TKey,TValue>, I was just curious

One thing to note is FrozenDictionary is an abstract class while ImmutableDictionary is a sealed class, the built-in implementions should be thread-safe.

"Provides an immutable, read-only dictionary" -- how could that be Thread-Unsafe? If it's create-once, you cannot have stale data while using it. Am I missing something?

@Fildor that is exactly my understanding I was just looking for some confirmation from the docs.

My guess would be that it is simply an oversight in documentation. If the contract has these requirements the only problem I could imagine would be mutability of the TValue .... so maybe it's one of those "mostly" thread-safe situations? If your TValue is immutable, too, it should be pretty hard to create a problem, however.

@Fildor being immutable and read-only is the external behavior of the collection. It's not guaranteeing that the internal data-structures of the collection are immutable. It is theoretically possible that the collection optimizes the internal storage of the data for performance reasons, each time a key is read. I believe that it's highly unlikely, but without support from the documentation I am not 100% sure.

@TheodorZoulias That sounds reasonable, yes. Which brings us back to "mostly thread-safe but maybe not always" ... which could be seen as "thread-safe enough for certain use cases" ...

@Fildor "thread-safe enough for certain use cases" requires that the use cases are specific and unambiguous. For example the Dictionary<K,V> is thread-safe for reading, when there are no writers. I know it because the documentations says so. Without support from the documentation, or at least some indirect indication of intention from other official source (like the GitHub), how can we say what are the thread-safe use cases for a frozen collection?

@TheodorZoulias " how can we say what are the thread-safe use cases" - We can't. That's really an oversight on MS's side, IMHO.

@Fildor if the type / comparer works in that way: that'll impact any collection, so: if ImmutableWhatever can make a thread-safety claim: so can FrozenWhatever

@MarcGravell Yes, I see now. And I totally agree with your considerations in your answer, too.

For anyone interested in this discussion, I have filed an issue as suggested by @MarcGravell. Here is the link: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/10339

In my considered opinion, this is a documentation bug and should be addressed as such; the intent is I'm 99.9% positive that this is a truly immutable and read-only entity, and if we ignore reflection abuse (because all bets are off there, on any type): it is thread-safe. The constructor is internal, so we don't need to be concerned about exotic custom implementations - just the in-box ones (empty, small, default, etc), which all appear (on a cursory inspection) to be implemented appropriately (this is not a definitive review, note).
IMO: log a documentation issue

Thanks for the answer. Interestingly enough the public api actually exposes something that can be used for internal modification. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.frozen.frozendictionary-2.getvaluerefornullref?view=net-8.0

@EnricoMassone That returns a readonly ref, so you'd have to use Unsafe to modify it. And if you're using unsafe code, all bets are always off

You are right, it is a readonly ref, not a plain ref. Thanks for pointing that out.

Update:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable?view=net-8.0
From above source:
"With immutable collections, you can:
.Share a collection in a way that its consumer can be assured that the collection never changes.
.Provide implicit thread safety in multi-threaded applications (no locks required to access collections).
...
"
I believe your assumption is right, if any object/collection is implemented immutable then i dont see any reason to worry about thread safely reading it. If it's clear that object wont be changed then no need to worry about reading it thread safe. But, there might be always a but case in programming :), as @marc-gravell explained we can be 99.9% sure. I think that tiny odd is the case that unless some bad code try to change object via reflection or  something externally messing with memory. That makes me wonder if there is a protection in .net at least for reflection.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.frozen.frozendictionary-2?view=net-8.0
From given source;
FrozenDictionary<TKey,TValue> is immutable and is optimized for situations where a dictionary is created infrequently but is used frequently at run time. It has a relatively high cost to create but provides excellent lookup performance. Thus, it is ideal for cases where a dictionary is created once, potentially at the startup of an application, and is used throughout the remainder of the life of the application.

"Thread safety means concurrent operations without causing race condition or deadlocks." -- I wouldn't put deadlocks in my definition of thread-safety. I would define thread-safety in more general terms, like ensuring correct behavior in a multithreaded environment. The typical outcome of a program that is lacking in the thread-safety department is crashes, unexpected behavior, data corruption and incorrect results.

Btw your answer is mostly off-topic. Apart from expressing your opinion/belief that the frozen collections are thread safe, you mention a lot of other stuff from the documentation that have little to do with supporting/strengthening your belief. The OP most likely already knows why the frozen collections exist, and what they are good for. They just want to know if these collections can be safely used concurrently from multiple threads, without synchronization.

"as @marc-gravell mentioned it's 99.9% safe" -- Marc didn't say that 999 out of 1000 uses of frozen collections are thread-safe, and 1 is not. He said that he is 99.9% confident that frozen collections are perfectly thread-safe.

@TheodorZoulias in the top link i gave .net specifically tells  that it's thread safe.
And I dont think it's ever possible to change any immutable object (except some hacky ways)  so my argument was basically if something is declared immutable then you shouldnt be able to change it's internal state (it's elements) thus there shouldnt be any problem reading it concurrently.

@TheodorZoulias thanks for pointing that edited that part, obviously he doesnt say 99.9% times it's thread safe (or maybe he implicitly mean that :) because there is always a possibility like reflections etc. as he mentioned ).

The first link in your answer is about the collections in the System.Collections.Immutable namespace. It's not about the collections in the  System.Collections.Frozen namespace. Assuming that whatever is true for the one namespace is also true for the other requires a leap of faith.

Reflection is a possibility for everything, including concurrent collections. We don't say that the ConcurrentDictionary<K,V> or the Lazy<T> are only 99,9% thread-safe because of reflection, so why should we say it for the FrozenDictionary<K,V>? Reflection is known to break all the rules in the language. Whoever uses reflection knowns that he walks with a loaded gun pointing to his feet.

@TheodorZoulias On the other hand, I would be very interested how an immutable data structure could be in thread safe. Lets just say that it's pretty hard to make something immutable not thread safe.

(not thread safe, not "in thread safe")

@MarkRotteveel sure. An example of an immutable collection with a mutable internal state is the ImmutableQueue<T>. When you enumerate it for the first time, the enumerator reads the private BackwardsReversed property, which lazily initializes the private _backwardsReversed field. There is a comment about thread-safety in the source code there.
